# .astimezone() adds two hours to the output time? Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input:

```
import datetime
import pytz

local_time = datetime.datetime.now()
utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

print("Naive local is {}, while naive utc is {}".format(local_time, utc_now))

aware_local_time = pytz.utc.localize(local_time).astimezone()
aware_utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(utc_now)

print("Aware local is {}, while aware utc is {}".format(aware_local_time, aware_utc_now))
```

Output:

```
Naive local is 2020-08-25 09:40:54.336255, while naive utc is 2020-08-25 07:40:54.336255
Aware local is 2020-08-25 11:40:54.336255+02:00, while aware utc is 2020-08-25 07:40:54.336255+00:00
```

As you can see, it adds two hours to the aware local time. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi dear I think you're creating little bit confusion here, you should use `utc_now` instead of `local_time` because as you know that `astimezone()` adjusting the date and time data so the result is the same UTC time as self, but in tz’s local time by **`adding`** the time difference between them.

After above here you can see the code.

```
import datetime
import pytz

local_time = datetime.datetime.now()
utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

print("Naive local is {}, while naive utc is {}".format(local_time, utc_now))

aware_local_time = pytz.utc.localize(utc_now).astimezone()
aware_utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(utc_now)

print("Aware local is {}, while aware utc is {}".format(aware_local_time, aware_utc_now))
```

Output:

```
Naive local is 2020-08-25 15:17:48.587211, while naive utc is 2020-08-25 10:17:48.587477
Aware local is 2020-08-25 15:17:48.587477+05:00, while aware utc is 2020-08-25 10:17:48.587477+00:00
```